# jquery daterangepicker ui 1.7

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I found daterangepicker ( http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/ ) and am trying to customize it.

The detail goes like this:

Selected should be shown by orange highlighting

Week - Select the current week from Sunday to Saturday and then allows the user to select any other week range where Sunday to Saturday will be selected

Month - Select the entire current month and then allows the user to flip months where the entire month block is selected.

Can anyone Help me out !!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

the plugin let you choose the theme : 
[daterangepicker_v2](http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/daterangepicker_v2/)

or try using firebug to manipulate the css

Comment: No this is not what i want. In case of Week: When user clicks on any of the date then that particular week should get highlighted i.e the whole row. In case of Month: When user clicks on any of the date then that particular month should get highlighted i.e all the row.